# Puedo ejecutar y modificar una aplicación a través de cmd?

Tags: cmd

Necesito saber que puedo hacer para ejecutar y modificar la misma ventana de la aplicación solo usando el `cmd`. Tengo entendido que puedo simular `clicks` dentro de la ventana con `Enter`, `F2`... así que no sé usar.
Si alguien sabe de que va o un método mejor; estoy atento. Adjunto imagen de la ventana.

[image: Captura de pantalla]

Específicamente, necesito solo rellenar los primeros dos campos con los directorios como aparece y presionar dos veces el botón **Execute**.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Te recomiendo hacer este [tour] para que veas cómo funciona la comunidad y de paso ganes tu primer medalla. Por su parte, estaría bien que revises [ask] y [repro] para que te hagas una idea de cómo preguntar. La idea es que aportes algo de código a tu pregunta (lo que hayas hecho hasta el momento para intentar resolver tu problema) y que des un poco más de contexto.

Comment: Respecto a tu pregunta puntual, depende mucho de la naturaleza del ejecutable que quieras lanzar desde cmd, por lo general depende de que el ejecutable esté en la capacidad de interpretar los argumentos pasados al ejecutable, intenta revisar la documentación del producto (el programa que quieres ejecutar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este tipo de preguntas son las que suelen ser eliminadas.
Pero si te sirve, el programa que mencionas "FastCopy" tiene la posibilidad de ejecutarse desde la línea de comandos. En [este enlace](https://fastcopy.jp/help/fastcopy_eng.htm#cmdline) tienes la documentación.

Por ejemplo:

```
fastopy.exe "C:\Temp" /to="D:\Backup\"
```

Esto copia archivos de una carpeta a otra, tienes otras opciones que deberás estudiar para que se ajusten a tus requerimientos (sobreescribir, etc.)